# Magnifying glass in flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield

Is there any package for adding **Magnifying glass** feature in flutter textfield when changing cursor position by long press swiping.

Comment: [magnifier.dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/magnifier.dart) - it is in flutter v3.4

Answer (score -1):

This package would be the solution to your issue: https://pub.dev/packages/magnifying_glass

```
dependencies:
  magnifying_glass: ^1.0.3
```